# Authorize an Org command is not working in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, salesforce, apex

I have installed latest version of VS Code and Salesforce Extension Pack version is 47.16.0.

[image]

I was able to authorize an org first time. Then I tried to authorize another org but browser is not opening to authorize the org. After running the command, vs code is showing only showing the running notification.

[image]

I have checked the Problems and Debug Console tab but there is no error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue going on for a while, at some point stopped working all of a sudden and the workaround listed here worked for me.

[SFDX: Authorize an Org doesn't open browser for OAuth #1888]
https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/1888

Apparently there seems to be an ongoing conflict between Chrome and Salesforce CLI.
Switching to Microsoft Edge as a default browser fixed this problem.

Comment: Hi, I switched the default browser multiple times, to Edge, back to Chrome, Firefox, but I am still having the same issue. The authorize window does not pop up. Is there any other fix?

Comment: Hi Ivo, I'm not aware of other fix for this problem, was ready to give up altogether when I came across this workaround. To this date every time I'm authorizing a new org I have to switch to Edge as my default. Try clearing your cache, closing all browser tabs and restarting your computer after changing the default.

Comment: Thank you, will try clearing cache and see if that would work. Thanks